# Data structures: alternatives to logic bitmap/pixmap

Tags: c++, game-engine

I have decided to rewrite an old Zatacka clone of mine. The old thing, running under Allegro 4, utilizes logic bitmap, that is a bitmap used for non-display purposes, reflecting directly the visible "what's on the screen and doesn't move" bitmap, but the integers stored in it represent logical meaning of things on screen, because the game got quite colorful. So the things that players see may be of any color possible, but game just remembers what kind of object each pixels represents.

The new clone is not supposed to use Allegro, so I could write the logic bitmap code myself. That said, I would appreciate if someone suggested some more efficient and precise alternatives.

Structure must be able to be kept up with bitmap/texture visible to players. Think about Worms game, but utilizing player invisible ground type variations, or something. In addition, following methods must be implemented:

- Checking if all pixels in a circle belong to a small (~6) set of "colors" given as a parameter.
- Painting all pixels in a circle with a single "color".
- Painting all pixels in a circle, (except/only) ones in small set of "colors" provided as a parameter, with a single "color".
- Painting a silhouette of rotated, preprocessed if you wish so, bitmap with a single "color". (That's the tricky one: would interpreting the bitmap as a stupid polygon with loads of right angles do the job?)

This is the minimum. If your structure supports shapes other than circles, that's great.

Comment: You keep talking about "pixels in a circle". That alone means you're restricting the solution to bitmaps. Vector graphics, the other logical alternative, do not work with pixels. E.g. your first test would be to check if a circle element intersects another element with the specified color.

Comment: I am restricting the structure so that it remains "discrete" in some way, but I am not restricting it to be a two-dimensional vector of integers representing the colors directly. For example, we could imagine a structure LZMA-ing the bitmap all the time (except that this would probably not be efficient).